# Do I need an AndroidManifest.xml when working with Phonegap?

Tags: android, push-notification, cordova, phonegap-build

I started my development with [Phonegap-start](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start) and has been building and testing for android with [Phonegap Build](http://build.phonegap.com). Now I want to implement push notifications, I've looked at [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) and when following the instructions from the README in step 2 they ask me to modify my AndroidManifest.xml. I don't have any AndroidManifest.xml file, neither does the Phonegap-start app or the PushPlugin example.

Do I need an AndroidManifest.xml? If yes, where do I found one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not if you use Phonegap Build. Then you only need the config.xml file.

Read more: [Plugin install instructions for Phonegap Build users at PhoneGap Build Docs](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins).

Answer (score 0):

Yes phone gap has an android manifest file

when you create a new project in phone gap it is present same as in android

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new PhoneGap for Android project, it automatically creates an AndroidManifest.xml file.  It should be in your project folder itself, right underneath the res-folder.

Your project structure should be:

- src
- gen [Generated Java Files]
- Android XXX
- Android Dependencies
- Referenced Libraries
- assets
- bin
- libs
- res
- AndroidManifest.xml
- proguard-project.txt
- project.properties

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to modify it. There is an inbuilt `AndroidManifest.xml` in your plugin.