# Phonegap permission accelerometer

Tags: android, cordova, accelerometer

I'm wrote an phonegap powered android app which requires the accelerometer. 
In the beginning it worked just fine but then »kind of suddenly« it stopped working and navigator.accelerometer became undefined. I guess after a google research that it is a permission problem.
In my /config.xml I have included the tag

```
<plugin name="Accelerometer" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener" />
```

and

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
```

I'm using the online phonegap build service.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write permissions on the manifest.xml file:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />
```

Comment: I thought that I won't need an manifest.xml file when using the online build service? 
see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787934/do-i-need-an-androidmanifest-xml-when-working-with-phonegap

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problem when adding in plugins. For some reason when I add in another plugin all the other plugins stop working.  I haven't narrowed down exactly when this happens but it sometimes happens if I try to add in a plugin after having built a platform.

What works for me is to create a brand new cordova app, add in all the plugins again and copy over my www directory.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. It looks like the problem was that I used the accelerometer parameter in the onSuccess callback multiple times.
Now I added:

```
    x = acceleration.x;
    y = acceleration.y;
    z = acceleration.z;
```

And in the function I work with x, y and z instead of acceleration.x …

I don't know why this is might be a problem, but it worked :)